# How to provide value from an input in ActionLink?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

In my Razor page I have an input box like this. I want to provide its contents as a parameter to the action link.

```
<input id="FullName" placeholder="Full name" />
@Html.ActionLink("beep", "Beep", new { Info = $("#FullName").val() })
```

I can access the value in the input box if I execute *$("#FullName").val()* from the console. However, it's not accepting the syntax in the action link (expects other characters, and such).

How can I retrieve the data and send it in?

Comment: Is this something you want done on keyup?

Comment: @DrewKennedy Nope, not really. I want to provide a value that's in the text box and I don't want to submit the form. I was trying *@Html.TextBox("FullName")* but it didn't got recognized in the action link.

Comment: Right, I'm just confused by what you want. It *sounds* like you want the value of the `Info` attribute to be bound to the value of the input. Is that right? You can do that on a jQuery keyup event and doesn't require a form submission.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Yupp, it's correct. That's what I want. However, I'd like the binding of the *Info* attribute to the contents of the *FullName* text box to be done in the Razor page code. Is it possible? Or is the jQuery approach the only way?

Comment: jQuery is probably your best bet. The inline JavaScript would be too insane. I'll provide you an HTML example that can be translated to your Razor code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to bind your input to your action link using jQuery:

```
var fullName = $("#FullName");
//change this selector to grab your ActionLink's ID
var anchorInfo = $("a");

fullName.on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    anchorInfo.attr("info", value);
    //logging the keystrokes getting to the Info attribute
    console.log(anchorInfo.attr("info"));
});
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/du94a4LL/4/) of the straight up HTML interpretation.

### EDIT

Fixed some bugs in the code. Should be good to go now.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I wonder if it'd be possible to put it in a script tag inside the page... I tried <script>$(document).ready(...)</script> but it didn't work out. Do I really have to add a JS file? For this specific case, I'd like to keep it all in the same file. It's a PoC.

Comment: It would totally be doable in a script tag in your Razor page. Just make sure jQuery is already available to it. :)

Comment: Ah, that's it. It's not available there. In the  console I have $ but in the script tag I do not...

Comment: Browsers (at least Chrome does) by default gives you jQuery in the console, that's why you had it there. Glad this helped!